# Creating a table with 2 columns and 2 more sub columns

Tags: tables

I am trying to create the following table:

[image]

I have tried the following but

```
    \begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{*6c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
    Class & Number           & Class & Number      \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: like this? : \begin{table}[htb]
 \centering
 \caption{Caption}
 \label{tab:example}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{B}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A}  \\ 
  \hline
  Class & Number           & Class & Number      \\ 
  \hline
  a & b & c & d \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: But what? You are apparently using `booktabs` but that doesn't work well with vertical lines (which it says is better not to use). And you are missing two `\cmidrule{3-4} ` s next to the `\cmidrule{1-2}.
So what else do you miss?

Comment: Like @PietervanOostrum said, I'd prefer the following: \begin{table}[htb]
 \centering
 \caption{Caption}
 \label{tab:example}
 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A}  \\ 
  \midrule
  Class & Number           & Class & Number      \\ 
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4}
  a & b & c & d \\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

What does `*6c` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Considering OP comment that table width should equal to `\textwidth`. For tis is used `tabularx` table environment:

With `makecell` ( for `\Xhline{...}` and `makegapedcells`) and `tabularx` package :

[image: first example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{4pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:example}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}  \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Class       & Number    & Class     & Number    \\  \hline
                &           &           &           \\  \hline
                &           &           &           \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

or without verical lines and with use of the  `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:example}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}  \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2}
    \cmidrule(l){3-4}
    Class       & Number    & Class     & Number    \\
    \midrule   
     aaa        & bbb       & ccc       & ddd       \\  
     aaa        & bbb       & ccc       & ddd       \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: second example]

Comment: Thank you, but it does not fit the page. How I can make it fit the border of the text?

Comment: @Avra, that is not clear from your question. I will redesign tables ASAP.

Comment: @Avra, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. Both working amazingly. The first one now is within the borders of the column as I used two column page.